# UIViewAutoresizing for siblings?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I know `UIViewAutoresizing` is relative to the superview. But, is there something like `UIViewAutoresizing` for siblings?

E.g., let's say I have a containerView with two subviews:

- containerView (height: 100)

  - subview1 (height: 30)
  - subview2 (height: 70)

Can I tell UIKit to automatically resize subview2 to fill the rest of containerView when subview1's height changes?

Right now, I'm making my view controller (VC) a delegate of subview1. subview1 then notifies the VC whenever its height changes, and the VC resizes subview2. But, I was wondering if there's an automatic way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not an automatic way to do it on iOS.  In Mac OS X Lion, Apple introduced constraint-based layout, which can do it.  Perhaps they will bring it to iOS in a future release, but for now you have to do it with code.

Comment: They did! Would you mind updating your answer with solution using constraints? I can't make it work. Thanks!